# How to make one out of all the li elements to be shown only if user is logged in? PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to make the logout li to be shown only if user is logged in. Menubar is under the leftsidebar.php file. The file is required by the index.php and the con_login.php does the verification.
I'm new to php so i'm not sure about how to do that. I tried some lines of code i find online but doesn't work

leftsidebar.php

```
<nav id="leftsidebar">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="page_public.php">Δημόσια Σελίδα</a></li>
        <li><a href="page_user.php">Σελίδα Χρήστη</a></li>

        <li><a href="con_logout.php">Logout</a></li>

      </ul>

    </nav>
```

index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
  $title="Super eShop - Home Page";
  require('part_header.php');
  require('part_leftsidebar.php');
?>
    <main id="main">
       <h2>Home Page</h2>

       <?php echo_msg(); ?>

       <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>

       <p>Please login:</p>
       <form name="form1" method="post" action="con_login.php">
         <p>username: <input type="text" name="username"/> </p>
         <p>password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </p>
         <p><input name="submit" type="submit"></p>
       </form>

       <?php } else echo '<p> Hello ' .$_SESSION['username'].'</p>';?>

    </main>

<?php require('part_footer.php'); ?>
```

con_login.php

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $authorised=false;

    if ($username=='test'){
        $authorised=true;
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
  }

    if ($authorised==true){
        header("Location: page_user.php");
        exit();}
    else{
        header("Location: index.php?msg=Αποτυχημένη διαπίστευση χρήστη!");
        exit();}
  }

else{
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php?msg=Πρόβλημα σύνδεσης. Ξαναδοκιμάστε!");
    exit();
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I get your question, but if `$authorised` says whether you're logged in or not, you could write s.th. like the following in your HTML / PHP file.

```
<nav id="leftsidebar">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="page_public.php">Δημόσια Σελίδα</a></li>
        <li><a href="page_user.php">Σελίδα Χρήστη</a></li>

        <?php echo ($authorised ? '<li><a href="con_logout.php">Logout</a></li>' : ''); ?>

    </ul>


</nav>
```

But this would require, that you set `$authorised` every time you call the page, alternatively, you could do it with a `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0):

If your code works as is, then you just need to set this in your sidebar

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>

   <li><a href="con_logout.php">Logout</a></li>

<?php } ?>
```